# File Name and Variable in Flume

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, flume

Right now I am working in a project where we are trying to read tomcat access log using flume and process those data in Spark and dump those in DB in proper format. But problem is that tomcat access log file is a daily rolling file and file name will change every day. Some thing like...

```
localhost_access_log.2017-09-19.txt
localhost_access_log.2017-09-18.txt
localhost_access_log.2017-09-17.txt
```

and my flume conf file for source section is something like

```
# Describe/configure the source
flumePullAgent.sources.nc1.type = exec
flumePullAgent.sources.nc1.command = tail -F /tomcatLog/localhost_access_log.2017-09-17.txt
#flumePullAgent.sources.nc1.selector.type = replicating
```

Which is running tail command on a fixed file name(I used fixed name , for testing only). How can I pass the file name as a parameter in flume conf file.

In fact , If some how I able to pass the file name as parameter , then also it will not be a actual solution. say , I start flume today with some file name (example : "localhost_access_log.2017-09-19.txt"), tomorrow when I will change the file name (localhost_access_log.2017-09-19.txt to localhost_access_log.2017-09-20.txt) some one has to stop the flume and restart with new file name. In that case it will not be a continues process, I have to stop / start the flume using cron job or something like this. Another problem is that I will loss some data(The server we are working now is high throughput server , 700-800 TPS almost ) every day during the processing time.(I mean time it will take to generate the new file name+time to stop flume+time to start flule)

Any one , have idea how to run flume with roll over file name in production environment? Any help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

`exec` source is not suitable for your task, you can instead use [Spooling Directory Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source). From Flume user guide:

> This source lets you ingest data by placing files to be ingested into a “spooling” directory on disk. This source will watch the specified directory for new files, and will parse events out of new files as they appear.

Then, in config file you'd mention your logs directory like this:

`agent.sources.spooling_src.spoolDir = /tomcatLog`